# How to package a cython module?

Tags: python, c++, pip, package, cython

I have some Cython wrapped C++ code that I want to package up. The package directory is structured like so:

```
.
├── PackageA
│   ├── Mypackage.pyx
│   ├── MyPackageC.cpp
│   ├── HeaderFile.h
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── setup.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
```

I have previously been making a shared object file by running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` using the setup.py file inside of the PackageA directory and importing the shared object file but I am unsure how to deal with this inside a package structure. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python setup.py install` should do the right thing. You can check it by doing `import PackageA` from a separate python session outside of the project folder.